# MP3 either plays or fails to play in IE9 and Firefox HTML5

Tags: html, firefox, audio, internet-explorer-9, mp3

I have a problem that I really can't figure what is going on. I have over 1,000 MP3 files on my website. They all play fine in Google Chrome...But, the MP3's either play or they don't play in Firefox and IE9. There seems to be some consistency though. For example, 929.MP3 will play in Firefox and IE9 but 930.mp3 won't play in Firefix or IE9. 929.mp3 and 930.mp3 will both play in Google Chrome.

If I convert the MP3 files to WebM or MP4 every file will play but I have unwanted audio quality loss or an unwanted larger file as a result of conversion. There has to be a better way to do it.

```
{* Begin Audio Add On *}
{assign var="wine"   
value="/home/tara/public_html/{$site}/audio/`$row.ID`.mp3"}
{if file_exists($wine)}
<tr><td colspan="2" height="10"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><p></p></td>
<td>
<audio controls preload="none">
<source src="{$site}/audio/{$row.ID}.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script>
{literal}
$(function(){
$('audio').panzerlist({theme: 'light'});
});
{/literal}
</script>
</td>
</tr>
{/if}
{* End Audio Add On *}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MP3 file was "corrupted" according to Firefox and IE9.

Of course, there is no way to tell if a file is actually "corrupted" as it plays fine in Chrome.